# CSS hover, z-index, and divs

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project for college and I am having trouble making a div change opacity from 0 to .9 when the user hovers over the div. I was wondering does the z-index affects how the hover works. I have tried the code in J Query and by using the CSS transition property and still receive the same results. NOTHING HAPPENS. Here is the code I used in CSS and HTML.

```
 <div class="special">
        <div class="spImage">
              <div>
                 <article>Lil Wayne</article>
              </div>
              <img id="special1" src="image/2pc.jpg" />
              <p>2pc<br>Dark<br>$1.30</p>

        </div>
   </div>


.spImage{
    border: 2px solid grey;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;

}

 .spImage div{
            background-color: orange;
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 250px;
            height: 330px;
            z-index: 0;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 10px orange;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;


        }


 .spImage div:hover{
            opacity: .8;
        }
```

My overall goal is to make the div appear over the div with a class of spImage. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index) determines an elements [stacking order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), in your example, you don't necessarily need to be using `z-index` at all since your HTML elements are *already* correctly positioned for what you are trying to do.

See the below example without the `z-index` property - if I understand your question correctly, this should be the expected behaviour:

```css
.spImage{
  border: 2px solid grey;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;

}

.spImage div{
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 330px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 10px orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.spImage div:hover{
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<div class="special">
  <div class="spImage">
    <div>
      <article>Lil Wayne</article>
    </div>
    <img id="special1" src="https://i.imgur.com/Ik7I6l7b.jpg" />
    <p>2pc<br>Dark<br>$1.30</p>
  </div>
</div>
```